# Proper way to checkout home directory .rc files from a git repo?

Tags: bash, git, rc

What is the proper way to checkout a bunch of `.*rc` files into a home directory?

I've seen lots of github repos online and people usually name them `dotfiles`, and I guess they get checked out into their home directory; but what I don't understand is...

How does one keep their other home files (specific to that machine) separate from their `.*rc` related files?

For instance, you would not want to store `/home/<username>/Documents` in the `dotfiles` git repo, but you would want to store `.vimrc`, `/home/vim` in the repository.

I'm aware of using `.gitignore` to ignore files for a repository, but I don't want to add an entry to `.gitignore` every single time I add a file to `/home/<username>/Documents`.  Is there a way to do this the opposite way, that I only specify the files and directories related to my `dotfiles` project to be included in the repository?

Also, if I create a new feature branch for something that I'm already developing, and I check it out, I don't want it to "blow away" the non-dotfiles folders etc when I check it out, or have `git` complain that the working directory isn't clean before cutting a new branch.

Would this somehow require the use of [git submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)?

What I'd really like to do with this is be able to get on a new Linux box and with the required dependencies installed check out a common version of my `.*rc` files and related files from my repo, so if I fix it on one, I can just pull the changes to the other machines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An option is to use symbolic links.  For example, say I have my git checkout out in `~/.dotfiles`.  I might have:

```
.vimrc      -> ~/.dotfiles/vimrc
.bashrc     -> ~/.dotfiles/bashrc
.bash_login -> ~/.dotfiles/bash_profile
...
```

I would not, personally, check my home directory itself into the repo.